# Generate protractor-cucumber html report

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor 5.2.2 with cucumber 3.2.0 and i need to generate html report on completion of running of feature file.What all are the steps to generate this report.Can anyone give a guidance.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your

```
try {
            reporter.generate({
    jsonFile: targetJson,
    output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
    theme: "bootstrap",
}); // invoke cucumber-html-reporter
        } catch (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error("Failed to save cucumber test results to json file.");
            }
        }
```

Below dependencies in your package.json

```
    "cucumber": "^3.0.4",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.0.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^4.0.8",
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I am using java script in protractor.I have tried below code in my conf.js
    var reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');
    onComplete: () => {
      reporter.generate({
      jsonFile: targetJson,
      output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
      reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
      theme: "bootstrap",
   });
And i am getting an  "Error: ReferenceError: targetJson is not defined"

Comment: If i am specifying Jason file as   jsonFile: '/cucumber_report.json',   then it shows  Error: ReferenceError: htmlReports is not defined

Comment: `var htmlReports = path.join(process.cwd(), "/reports/html");`
use this and try

Comment: when i have used above code,it shows  ReferenceError: path is not defined. so i have added var path = require("path"); then it shows  TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

Comment: I have created files cucumber_reporter.json and cucumber_reporter.html and used below code in my cucumber.conf.js

var reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');
var htmlReports = process.cwd() + "test/report/html";
onComplete: () => {
      reporter.generate({
      jsonFile: 'test/report/cucumber_reporter.json',
      output: htmlReports + "test/report/cucumber_reporter.html",
      reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
      theme: "bootstrap",
   });

Comment: Now it showng Unable to parse cucumberjs output into json: 'test/report/cucumber_reporter.json
' SyntaxError: test/report/cucumber_reporter.json: Unexpected end of JSON input. am i going wrong?